# Probability over a circular region

Tags: r, probability, normal-distribution

Suppose *z* is a bivariate normal (Gaussian) random variable with mean at *s* and covariance matrix *b^2 I_2*. I want to get the probability over the area *||x-s|| <= r* for some fixed point *x* and constant *r > 0*. I was using R software to compute it. The following is an example of the way I tried to estimate the probability -

```
library(mvtnorm)
e2dist=function(x,y) # x is vector, y is matrix
{
  a=sqrt((x[1]-y[,1])^2 + (x[2]-y[,2])^2)
  return(a)
}
r=0.5
b=1
s=c(0.1,0.1)
x=c(0,0)
a1=seq(x[1]-r, x[1]+r, length.out=1000)
a2=seq(x[2]-r, x[2]+r, length.out=1000)
grid.pts=as.matrix(expand.grid(a1,a2))
ttt=e2dist(s,grid.pts)<=r
tt=which(ttt==T, arr.ind=T)
circle.in.pts=grid.pts[tt,]
mean(dmvnorm(circle.in.pts,s,b*diag(2)))
> [1] 0.1503632
```

This estimate of the probability is not right as when I compute the true probability over the square area (x-c(r,r)) to (x+c(r,r))

```
pmvnorm(lower=c(x[1]-r, x[2]-r), upper=c(x[1]+r, x[2]+r), mean=s, sigma=b*diag(2))[[1]]
> [1] 0.1452895
```

which is not possible (as the square is larger than the circle). I know there is something wrong, but could not find out. Can you help me to find the probability over the circular area ?

P.S. 1) The function 'e2dist' computes the euclidean distance between two points.

2) Both dmvnorm and pmvnorm are from package 'mvtnorm'.

Comment: From which package(s) come functions `e2dist` and `dmvnorm`?

Comment: I believe `pmvnorm(lower=c(x[1]-r, x[2]-r), upper=c(x[1]+r, x[2]+r), mean=s, sigma=b*diag(2))[[1]]` returns probability in the _circular_ area bounded by `lower` and `upper` not the square area as suggested in your question.

Comment: @Pascal I have edited the question. Sorry for the trouble. The function e2dist has been used in many r packages on spatial modelling. But anyway I should have given explanation.

Comment: @ChrisHolbrook Sorry to disagree with you. pmvnorm computes the distribution function of normal with arbitrary limits and parameters. Go through the page [link](http://www.stat.fsu.edu/~jfrade/HOMEWORKS/STA5166/hw4/mvtnorm/html/pmvnorm.html).

Comment: I know that Riemann Integration holds for rectangular domain. I tried this approach just to see how close it goes as I had no clue about the correct way to compute the probability over a circle.

Comment: @Pascal you are correct

Comment: If `x` `s` and `r` are fixed there is no area. Did you mean the area `A={x| ||x_0-x||<=r}`, the circle with radius r around `x_0` (while the density is still centered around `s`)? Currently you select the points with Euclidean distance to s <= r from a grid of points with Manhattan distance to x <= r. In any case, you compute the average density in an area; to get a probability you have to multiply the mean density by the size of the area.

Comment: In general, to (analytically) compute an integral over an circle it might be beneficial to [transform your coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) to [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) (with the center in the middle of the circle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this probability with the `shotGroups` package:

```
> library(shotGroups)
> pmvnEll(r=0.5, sigma=diag(2), mu=c(0.1,0.1), e=diag(2), x0=c(0,0))
[1] 0.1164051
```

More generally, the `pmvnEll` function returns the probability of an offset ellipsoidal region for a multivariate (not only bivariate) normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brute force approach:

using these from the question:

```
library(mvtnorm)
e2dist=function(x,y) # x is vector, y is matrix
{
  a=sqrt((x[1]-y[,1])^2 + (x[2]-y[,2])^2)
  return(a)
}
r=0.5
b=1
s=c(0.1,0.1)
x=c(0,0)
```

draw large sample from multivariate normal distribution and calculate the proportion of those samples in the area of interest

```
y <- rmvnorm(1000000,mean=s, sigma=b*diag(2))

#proportion of mvn distn in circular region (radius r) centered at x
dyx <- e2dist(x,y) #distances between y and x
mean(dyx < r)
>[1] 0.117238

#proportion of mvn distn in circular region (radius r) centered at s
dys <- e2dist(s,y) #distances between y and s
mean(dys < r)
>[1] 0.118308
```

for square region, the result is close agreement with `pmvnorm` but very large number of random samples may be needed

```
#proportion of mvn distn in square region
mean( y[,1] >= -r & y[,1] <= r &
      y[,2] >= -r & y[,2] <= r)
>[1] 0.145965

#compare to...
pmvnorm(lower=c(x[1]-r, x[2]-r), upper=c(x[1]+r, x[2]+r), mean=s, 
      sigma=b*diag(2))[[1]]
>[1] 0.1452895
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend my comments:
Your approach is in principle correct, fixing two mistakes yields an approximatey correct result:

```
library(mvtnorm)
e2dist=function(x,y) # x is vector, y is matrix
{
    a=sqrt((x[1]-y[,1])^2 + (x[2]-y[,2])^2)
    return(a)
}
r=0.5
b=1
s=c(0.1,0.1)
x=c(0,0)
a1=seq(x[1]-r, x[1]+r, length.out=1000)
a2=seq(x[2]-r, x[2]+r, length.out=1000)
grid.pts=as.matrix(expand.grid(a1,a2))
ttt=e2dist(x,grid.pts)<=r                               # circle is centered around x not s
tt=which(ttt==T, arr.ind=T)
circle.in.pts=grid.pts[tt,]
mean(dmvnorm(circle.in.pts,s,b*diag(2))) * pi*r^2         # need to multiply by area

# Output:
# [1] 0.1164057
```